# How to create a laser in Cycles using the sun and nodes (by following a youtube tutorial)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I'm trying to reproduce [this tutorial's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84jVF5ikFck) top comment. However I'm failing on the very first paragraph:

> If you set the light to "sun", the laser should be a real laser. I mean, the sunlight in blender is parallel, independently from the sun's position

Point light works:
[image: pic]

Sun light per instruction:
[image: pic]

[image]

HDRI: https://polyhaven.com/a/aircraft_workshop_01

Comment: I don't think a sun lamp will work. The comment is right as far as it goes, the Sun lamp rays are parallel to each other. But the rays aren't limited to a narrow beam, so they will illuminate everything, not just the section you want to appear as the laser path.

Comment: Tut doesnt use sun light, only point light ... comment is probably just theoretical thought, if you read all comments there is no one confirming functionality. Sun is not working for me too.

Comment: Marty. Vklidu. I'm taking this opportunity to thank both of you for your endless patience in the last years. Happy new year.

Comment: Happy New Year @jjk